# Detectar niveles de un array variables y ponerlos en select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, array, arraylist

tengo una duda muy grande con respecto a poner un array ordenadamente en unos selects, tengo el siguiente array que tiene esta estructura:

```
array (size=4)
  'Azul' => 
    array (size=2)
      '128GB' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Cristal' => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Cristal' => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
  'Blanco' => 
    array (size=2)
      '32GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Madera' => string 'Madera' (length=6)
  'Dorado' => 
    array (size=1)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Plastico' => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
  'Verde' => 
    array (size=1)
      '64GB' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Madera' => string 'Madera' (length=6)
```

Quiero que en los select que ya se generan automaticamente como sel1, sel2, sel3 se cargue la información de cada nivel, por ejemplo:

```
SEL1 = Azul
SEL2 = 64GB, 128GB
SEL3 = La opción que se selecciona con Azul + el SEL2
```

Tengo este codigo en JQUERY que carga el primer select SEL1:

```
let arrResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                
$.each(arrResponse, function(key, value) { //Array Madre
    $('#selItem0').append(new Option(key, key)); //Primer nivel, carga todos
});
```

No tengo idea de como ir en cada nivel o detectarlo para que aparezcan en cada select, si alguien puede darme una ayuda le agradeceré enormemente

Comment: Realmente no era necesario poner ese formato Array - Objeto al inicio, pues solo te estas complicando mas de lo que necesitas, pero ojo, no estoy criticando eso, se aprecia el esfuerzo realizado, pues eso habra llevado su tiempo, sin embargo no me queda claro porque te gustaria mostrar la informacion de esa manera, pues los selects no estan relacionados de ninguna forma con los otros (en el sentido de que naturalmente estos no van a interactuar entre ellos o por lo menos no de manera natural), creo que una tabla seria mejor para mostrar esa informacion

Comment: Es decir, te propongo que los selects te ayuden a seleccionar valga la redundancia a  la informacion que necesitas, y que luego esta informacion sea mostrada de manera organizada y a tiempo real en una tabla con sus relaciones.

Comment: Hola @Riven gracias por tomarte el tiempo en leer mi duda, la estructura es mas facil asi porque al hacer la seleccion llevará el nombre y lo compara directamente con el key que es del mismio nombre.

Comment: el problema como te digo son los niveles, pues los selects no tienen relacion directa en terminos de funcionalidad con los otros, para poder digamos que pueda realizarse lo que intentas tendrias que programar el funcionamiento de cada uno de los selects teniendo en cuenta los otros para que estos cambien de acuerdo a las opciones. y pues no hay nested selects... asi que es un poco mas complicado...